# Error in Calculated Field during integration of R with Tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api, outliers

I have tried creating a calculated field in Tableau that identifies outliers using the boxplot.stats() function of R. The data I have used is the superstore sample of Tableau 9.1. Below is the calculated field I created:

```
1 SCRIPT_REAL('
2 counts=.arg1
3  sales=.arg2
4
5  num<-numeric()
6  cntr<-1
7
8  for(i in 1:length(counts)){
9    num[cntr]<-sales[i]
10    cntr<-cntr+1
11  }
12
13  salesout<-boxplot.stats(num)$out
14
15  if(length(salesout)>0){
16     
17     verify<-FALSE
18
19      for(i in 1:length(salesout)){
20          if(salesout[i]==sales){
21              verify<-TRUE
22              break
23          }
24      }
25      
26      if(verify==FALSE){
27        return(0)
28      }else{
29        return(1)
30      }
31
32  }else{
33     return(0)
34  }
35
36 ',COUNT([Sales]),SUM([Sales])
37 )
```

Getting the outliers was accomplished using the function boxplot.stats but it failed to identify whether a specific value should be an outlier or not. I have attached the sample result below:[image]

The problem was that when compared to sales, **line 20 in R**, across the table, it is **compared only to the first value of the table not the current value**. What is the workaround for this problem? I have tried the pracma package but it seems it has different result compared to other techniques.

Any help would be great. Thank you very much!

Comment: How do your `.arg1` and `.arg2` look like?

Comment: Hi. They are both numeric.

Comment: but what is the length?